# JNI error: while using android apksignertool

Tags: java, apksigner

I was trying to create a sample android application without using android-studio.While I tried to sign the package by `$APKSIGNER sign --ks mykey.keystore bin/hello.unaligned.apk` I got the following error.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/apksigner/ApkSignerTool has 
been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the 
Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I am using openjdk 1.8.0_265 on fedora32. Does it have something to do with jdk ?

Comment: version 53 corresponds to Java 9

Comment: @Botje So should I install openjdk 9 then ?

Comment: It's worth a shot. I cannot find anything about this in the release notes though. What versions of Android build tools do you have?

Comment: @Botje build-tools version-- 30.0.1

Comment: It looks like [Google reverted the Java SDK requirement for apksigner](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/tools/apksig/+/1379679) two weeks ago. You should probably not be using release candidates in your daily work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

version 53.0 means using java version 9, and you current jre is version 8, which can not run java 9 codes.

so download and configure to use jre 9.

[download link](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/9)

Comment: I would link to one of the OpenJDK implementations rather than Oracle's official builds because of the latter's questionable licensing.

Comment: @Botje I installed openjdk 14 .And it works fine.Thanks for the help.